# GCC atomic builtins, port to Windows/Visual Studio

Tags: c, windows, gcc, atomic, interlocked

I am working on a project that depends on GCC's [atomic built-ins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html). While porting the project to Windows, I was trying to find the Interlocked* counterparts for GCC atomics. Most operations are actually available, but I miss operations that apply `__ATOMIC_CONSUME` and `__ATOMIC_ACQ_REL` memory semantics. As _*Barrier intrinsics are [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f20w0x5e.aspx), Microsoft [advises](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874633.aspx) to use `std::atomic` (e.g. `atomic_thread_fence`) and alike of the C++11 standard.

I was wondering: What is the C programmer supposed to do and how can we implement a portable version of `atomics` with `__ATOMIC_CONSUME` and `__ATOMIC_ACQ_REL` semantics, without using C++11?

Comment: of course, a "correct" approach could be to fallback to the stronger semantics, i.e. __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE and __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST, respectively...

Comment: Does Visual Studio 2013 support C11? I think it only has std::atomic...

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using parts of [mintomics](http://preshing.com/20130505/introducing-mintomic-a-small-portable-lock-free-api/)